# Dart SQLJocky and Mariadb Local Connection Problems

Tags: mysql, dart, mariadb

I can't seem to get sqljocky + Dart to connect to my local Mariadb(MySQL) database. I can use Golang with github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and it connects with

```
sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@unix(/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)/dbname")
```

I'm not sure what the problem is and I have search here and elsewhere. Any ideas?

Note: This is the line I use in Dart and when I ping I get a connection error.

```
var pool = new ConnectionPool(host: 'localhost', port: 3306, user: 'username', password: 'password', db: 'dbname', max: 5);
```

Also: The Dart program is not a web application, its a command-line application.

Comment: This the error message I received - SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 42224

Comment: Can you try `127.0.0.1` instead - just to be sure - there were some issues caused by this difference in the past.

Comment: I get the same error message - SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 42461

Comment: I did a status query on my MariaDB and got this info

Server:               MariaDB                                                                                                                                                                                    
Server version:         5.5.38-MariaDB Mageia MariaDB Server

Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket

UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: You don't have some special characters like `$` in the username or password you use? You can try to prefix the connection string with an `r` like `r'username'`, `r'password'` Can you also please try `telnet localhost 3306` and add to your question what response you get on the console? See also http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mysql-connection-refused-134096/

Comment: This might be relevant too https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I looked around some more and its turns out that some dart programmers claim that recent versions of the dart:io package doesn't support Unix sockets.

I guess that ends the discussion with Dart's io package just doesn't support that right now. I guess I'll have to find a way to get Mariadb to start-up with-out a Unix socket.

Cheers - Thanks for the input.

Note: If you comment out 'skip-networking' in the Mariadb /etc/my.cng then you can connect with sqljocky.